# How much to each part?

Tags: project, business

I have been involved in a project and now it is coming to an end. The good news is the company will start to commercialize the software which is specific software to ISPs. 
As a programmer / developer of the project, I intend to still support the project, attend to new custommer customizations, basically the software will still alive and be sold in the market.

How much should I charge to stay ON the project? Should I charge per hour? per month? or even by percent over each customer?

What is the default for this kind of situation? or How do most programmers/developers deal with that?

Thanks in advance, It is a very important question to me.

Comment: Are you working as a freelance developer? Was the software developed on a contract basis?

Comment: @Bernard is a kind of freelance agreement, no contract yet. But I think will need a contract soon, since starts to sell in the market. I'm just looking for a reference in how to charge this. A Fix value  + percent over the incoming ? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. find out how valuable are your services to the company selling the software
2. charge them that amount

Comment: Point 1 is often hidden / obfuscated. So if your skills are on coding and not on investigative work, what would you do?

Comment: @Pacerier: ask.

Answer (score 1):

I would charge the same amount for a period of time and then raise the fee if the project is successful and your contribution remains integral.